# How to write streaming data to S3?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

I want to write `RDD[String]` to Amazon S3 in Spark Streaming using Scala. These are basically JSON strings. Not sure how to do it more efficiently. 
I found [this post](https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/02/08/saving-spark-dataframes-on-amazon-s3-got-easier/), in which the library `spark-s3` is used. The idea is to create `SparkContext` and then `SQLContext`. After this the author of the post does something like this:

```
myDstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
      rdd.toDF().write
                .format("com.knoldus.spark.s3")
                .option("accessKey","s3_access_key")
                .option("secretKey","s3_secret_key")
                .option("bucket","bucket_name")
                .option("fileType","json")
                .save("sample.json")
}
```

What are another options besides `spark-s3`? Is it possible to **append** the file on S3 with the streaming data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look into mode method for dataframewriter in [Spark Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/index.html):

> `public DataFrameWriter mode(SaveMode saveMode)`
>
> Specifies the behavior when data or table already exists. Options
>   include: - SaveMode.Overwrite: overwrite the existing data. -
>   **SaveMode.Append: append the data**. - SaveMode.Ignore: ignore the
>   operation (i.e. no-op). - SaveMode.ErrorIfExists: default option,
>   throw an exception at runtime.

You can try somethling like this with **Append** savemode.

```
rdd.toDF.write
        .format("json")
        .mode(SaveMode.Append)
        .saveAsTextFile("s3://iiiii/ttttt.json");
```

[Spark Append:](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html#Append)

> Append mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if
>   data/table already exists, contents of the DataFrame are expected to
>   be appended to existing data.

Basically you can choose which format you want as an output format by passing "format" keyword to method

> `public DataFrameWriter format(java.lang.String source)`
>
> Specifies the underlying output data source. Built-in options include "parquet", "json", etc.

eg as `parquet`:

`df.write().format("parquet").save("yourfile.parquet")`

or as `json`:

`df.write().format("json").save("yourfile.json")`

---

***Edit: Added details about s3 credentials:***

there are two different options how to set credentials and we can see this in [`SparkHadoopUtil.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkHadoopUtil.scala#L82)
with environment variables `System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")`  or with `spark.hadoop.foo` property:

```
SparkHadoopUtil.scala:
if (key.startsWith("spark.hadoop.")) {
          hadoopConf.set(key.substring("spark.hadoop.".length), value)
}
```

so, you need to get `hadoopConfiguration` in [javaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContext.html#hadoopConfiguration()) or [scalaSparkContext.hadoopConfiguration](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@hadoopConfiguration:org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration) and set

```
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", myAccessKey)
hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", mySecretKey)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the cleaner option would be to use `saveAsTextFile` of Spark, instead of using `spark-s3`?

Comment: In your first example where should I put the Amazon access key and pass?

Comment: 1, @Lobsterrrr I think yes `saveAsTextFile` is provided by spark api. 2, And as @jbird noticed it is actually not verbatim appending. Appending in big data for me does not make a big sense - better way is to create partitions for example

Answer (score 3):

Files on S3 [cannot be appended](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=540395). An "append" means in S3 to replace the existing object with a new object that contains the additional data.

Comment: That is a good point: Lets suppose file already exists in S3. Spark states that data will be appended. Does it mean that spark will run several processes: something like create_new_data_file -> get_existing_file -> merge_files -> replace_file_on_S3? It does not look like atomic operation to me. If smth goes wrong - what will happen?